# How to create callback function in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this method with onTap parameter

```
myFunc({onTap}){
   return onTap;
}
```

then, I need to use it like this

```
myFunc(
   onTap: print('lorem ipsum');
)
```

How I can make it correctly? thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do like below. Note that you can specify parameter or avoid and I have added `Function`(You can use [ValueChange](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueChanged.html), [Voidcallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html))

```
myFunc({Function onTap}){
   onTap();
}

//invoke
myFunc(onTap: () {});
```

If you want to pass arguments:

```
myFunc({Function onTap}){
   onTap("hello");
}

//invoke
myFunc(onTap: (String text) {});
```

Comment: could you explain a little more why use Function keyword,  please

Comment: @ROB Its a type in dart for function. Indicating that the parameter is type of function. You must pass a argument type of function(Just like other variable types. Ex: `String`).

Answer (score 7):

A more exhaustive usage could be like

```
void main() {
  callbackDemo(onCancel: () {
     print("Cancelled");
  }, onResend: () {
     print("Resend");
  }, onSuccess: (otp) {
     print(otp);
 });
}

void callbackDemo({required onSuccess(String otp), 
onCancel, onResend}) {
  onCancel();
  onResend();
  onSuccess("123456");
}
```

Comment: I like this example :)

Answer (score 4):

The previous solution complicates matters by using named parameters. Here is the simplest possible function that takes a callback function without any of the extra complexity:

```dart
testFunction(Function func){
    func();
}

void main() {
    testFunction( () {
        print('function being called');
    });
}
```

The `testFunction()` is defined as taking a function with no arguments (hence the data type of `Function`. When we call the function we pass an anonymous function as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that adds type safety to the parameters of the callback:

The callback takes in a parameter of type `T`, and another parameter of type `int`.

```
  void forEach(Function(T, int) cb){
    Node<T>? current = head;
    int index = 0;
    while (current != null){
      cb(current.value, index);
      index++;
      current = current.next;
    }
  }
```

Calling it:

```
list.forEach((v, i){
    print(v);
});
```